# how to copy some columns from deferent tables into another table using sql statement

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am very stressful with Sql coding. Any solution please help....
I have tables like below :

```
  OrderedFood(**TableID,FoodID**,Qty,OrderedDate)
  Invoices(**InvoiceID**,TableID,Amount)
  InvoiceDetail(**InvoiceID,FoodID**,Qty,orderedDate)
```

I want to copy OrderedFood.TableID => Invoices.TableID. then copy OrderedFood.FoodID => InvoiceDetail.FoodID , OrderedFood.Qty => InvoiceDetail.Qty which this content a lot of rows.

How could i do it ?

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: I don't think you can do it this way; cause you are not simply coping the data (in which case an insert would have been enough) but you are trying to copy/add columns to your existing table which needs table to be restructured.

Comment: yes, that is what i want. do you have any idea to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it is a bit hard to understand exactly what you are trying to do.
Hopefully the following SQL can help point you in the right direction

```
DECLARE @OrderedFood Table(TableID int ,FoodID int ,Qty int ,OrderedDate datetime)
DECLARE @Invoices Table(InvoiceID int IDENTITY(1,1)PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, TableID int ,Amount money)
DECLARE @InvoiceDetail Table(InvoiceID int,FoodID int,Qty int ,orderedDate datetime)

insert into @orderedfood values(1,1,1,'2010/05/21')
insert into @orderedfood values(1,2,3,'2010/05/21')
insert into @orderedfood values(1,3,2,'2010/05/21')
insert into @orderedfood values(2,1,4,'2010/05/21')
insert into @orderedfood values(2,2,2,'2010/05/21')

insert into @Invoices(TableId) SELECT distinct TableId From @OrderedFood

Insert into @InvoiceDetail(InvoiceID,FoodID,Qty,orderedDate)
SELECT InvoiceID,FoodId,Qty,OrderedDate 
FROM @OrderedFood o
inner join @Invoices i on o.tableid = i.tableid

select * from @invoices i inner join @invoicedetail id on i.invoiceid = id.invoiceid
```

Comment: Oh, that is the real solution. Thank you Mark

Answer (score 1):

You should use `INSER INTO ....SELECT` type query for example

```
INSERT INTO table1 ( column1 )
SELECT  col1
FROM    table2
```

other one is `SELECT INTO` Statement

```
SELECT column_name(s)
INTO new_table_name [IN externaldatabase]
FROM old_tablename
```

Comment: look, i want to copy Invoices.InvoiceID => InvoiceDetail.InvoiceID

Comment: and at the same time, copy OrderedFood.FoodID => InvoiceDetail.FoodID , OrderedFood.Qty => InvoiceDetail.Qty